# Duplicate launchpad icons where can I find the apps ?

Tags: macos, icon, launchpad

I have this strange behavior on Mac OS X Mountain Lion when I installed OpenSceneGraph. Please How to fix it ? I have duplicate icons on the launchpad. I 've tried the following solution : [How Do I Remove Duplicate Apps From Launchpad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34380/34196) I recreate the launchpad database but nothing !

How can I check where those apps are installed ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was having duplicates on my Launchpad, I used Launchpad-Control to remove them. It says it has serious issues on Mountain Lion, but I used it without any problems at all.